# Pass me the book (title)

Tags: grammar

The title of the book is foo.

1. Pass me the book foo.
2. Pass me the foo book.
3. Read the book foo.
4. Read the foo book.

Which ones are correct?

Comment: Can you capitalize and quote 'Foo'?

Answer (score 5):

I'd put the name of the book between quotes:

> Pass me the book 'Nineteen Eighty-Four'.
>
> Read the book 'Nineteen Eighty-Four'.

You can use the other two if 'foo' is the subject of the book, e.g.

> Pass me the programming book.
>
> Read the programming book.

Comment: "..in quotes". Are you slipping this note to a friend in the library during study hall?

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking to someone, you could ask

**Could you please pass me that copy of the maze maker?**

If you are sending someone a message:

**Could you please remember to include my copy of *The Maze Maker* in the box?**